# Configure Apache reverse proxy and regular virtual host

Tags: linux, apache

I've read several posts like mine, but none of them seem to work.

I've got a regular apache config on **CentOS 7** with a working website, both HTTP and HTTPS (certbot).

I have another service with a web port of `:3000 and i'd like to have it work as such:

> **http(s)://example.com**  *(regular website content)*
>
> **http(s)://example.com/new_site**  *(the service on port 3000)*

I've got the website set up as a virtual host with a custom webroot in `/var/www/example.com/docroot`

This is my current working config. I realized that the connection between the *localhost* does not need to be HTTPS, just the incoming requests:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ProxyPass /my_site http://localhost:3000
    ProxyPassReverse /my_site http://localhost:3000
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/my_vhost_log
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I also cleared up permissions issues by enabling the `httpd_can_network_connect SELinux boolean`.

UPDATE:

My issue now is that the above config overwrites my regular website content, so if you go to the https://example.com, it will just show the Apache welcome page, rather than the content in the `/var/www/example.com/docroot`.

Main config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/docroot
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Not sure about the non-ssl option - but for the SSL option, apache2 acts as an ssl endpoint and therefore would also need ssl certificates installed an enabled. How about accessing https://localhost:3000 vs. http://localhost:3000 via your web browser? Which of these works?

Comment: the ssl certificates are installed and configured properly. They work if I go to https://example.com:3000 which is fine, but the virtual hosts configuration doesn't work, which is where i'm looking for help.

Comment: Is your Apache compiled with the proxy module?  Then are the modules loaded?  Do you get any error log?  Change `LogLevel debug`, restart, try again.

Comment: Oh, sorry - I just assumed that there was something wrong with the ssl configuration in the proxy apache2 on port 443, because you got an "Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG". Do you get that message in the browser, or in the logs on the proxy?

Comment: You should be proxying to ``http://localhost:3000`` in both 80/443 virtual hosts. The one port 3000 can't be accepting both HTTP and HTTPS at the same time.

Comment: I updated the OP with more info. I'm currently just working on the 443 and am not handling any traffic from 80 for my service on 3000.

Answer (score 0):

In the event that anyone comes across this,

The fix is simply to add the Proxy lines to your main domain config. You only need a single config file.